# Gitlab CI + Git Flow: How to separate branch builds?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I develop a complex web application, employing `git flow`, Gitlab and a CI pipeline to deploy test builds to a testing machine, and master builds to a live staging system.

The build pipeline for both systems is the same, only with different deployment jobs:

```
require:
  stage: require
  only:
    - develop
    - tags
  tags:
    - require
  script:
    - npm install

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
    - tags
  script:
    - grunt

deploy_testing:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - (...)

deploy_master:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - (...)
```

Now I do a Git Flow hotfix, creating a commit on my `develop` branch, and a tagged commit on `master`. After pushing, Gitlab CI will run the jobs in this order:

1. `require` (checking out commit A on `develop`)
2. `require` (checking out tagged commit B on `master`)
3. `build`
4. `build`
5. `deploy_testing`
6. `deploy_master`

Sadly there is only one runner, meaning there is only one folder the jobs are run in. This means, that **step 3 will be executed with files from step 2, which is on a different branch**, and so on.
After running the whole pipeline, the testing system contains a similar state as the master/live staging system, which is not at all what I want.

How can I keep the two processes separate?
I already tried out separate `require` and `build` jobs explicitly only for `develop` and `tags`, but that didn't work as expected.

Is there a way to have different build folders, or to force Gitlab CI to run the jobs in a different order without that ping pong?

Answer (score 1):

This documentation can help you

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts

Maybe some code like

```
require:
  stage: require
  only:
    - develop
    - tags
  tags:
    - require
  script:
    - npm install

build_develop:
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - grunt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - folder_path_attached_to_deploy_job_develop

build_master:
  stage: build
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - grunt
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - folder_path_attached_to_deploy_job_master

deploy_testing:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - (...)
  dependencies:
  - build_develop

deploy_master:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - (...)
  dependencies:
  - build_master
```

Comment: Yes, it looks as if `dependencies` and `artifacts` are a way to make this work.

Comment: In my case it did not, because the artifacts are too large and would clutter my Gitlab instance with gigabytes of garbage.

I resorted in not quite solving this issue - now I never push both `develop` and tags together. Before pushing a tag, I wait until the `develop` build is finished.

Comment: then your problem isnt gitlab or git flow, is your application. Maybe you need change your strategy, installing and building your deps inside a docker image and deploying your docker image